# How to return the duplicate objects of two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say we have:

```
var array1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 4}, { id: 3 }] 
var array2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}]
```

I know you can concat the two arrays like this (without having duplicates):

```
Array.from(new Set(array1.concat(array2)))
```

Now, how to create a new array with **only** the objects that share the same values?

```
var array2 = [{ id: 1 }]
```

Comment: Not exactly, I think, as here there isn't proof that the objects are really the same, just equivalent.

Comment: you need the same object in `array2` for filtering.

Comment: Anyways, use lodash for this sort of stuff `_.intersectionBy(array1, array2, _.eq)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a set with the `id` of the objects and filter `array2`

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 4}, { id: 3 }] ,
    array2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}],
    s = new Set(array1.map(({ id }) => id)),
    common = array2.filter(({ id }) => s.has(id));
    
console.log(common);
```

The requested sameness with identical objects.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 4}, { id: 3 }] ,
    array2 = [array1[0], { id: 2}],
    s = new Set(array1),
    common = array2.filter(o => s.has(o));
    
console.log(common);
```

Comment: I just want them to be equivalent, without relying in any value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.filter()` and `.some()` to extract matching elements:

```js
let array1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 4}, { id: 3 }] 
let array2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}] 

let result = array1.filter(({id}) => array2.some(o => o.id === id));

console.log(result);
```

**Useful Resources:**

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: I just want them to be equivalent, without relying in any value.

Comment: @alex I didn't get your point. Can you be more specific what you wants?

Comment: @alex Do you wants to match all properties (not just one) of an object in `array1` with any object in `array2`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, by your definition, that the objects, even if they have the same structure, are not really the same object, I define an 'equality function', and then, with `filter` and `some`:

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 4}, { id: 3 }] 
var array2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}];

var equal = function(o1, o2) { return o1.id === o2.id };

var result = array2.filter(function(item1) {
  return array1.some(function(item2) { return equal(item1, item2) });
});

console.log(result);
```